# nVIDIA drivers installation keep messing up my install

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

TL;DR : I've changed the graphic drivers to be used in Ubuntu [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo3gI.jpg) and now it won't display anything. Please help me revert this.

SO : I've been trying to install nVIDIA drivers so that I can use my GC in blender or any other application as I do in windows. First I tried with terminal commands found on this site but ended up with no display. Could not repair it using the terminal in failsafe mode, so I had to reinstall the whole thing, which ended up being a pain in the ass to figure out as the install was using the swap partition on the drive I wanted to wipe. Took me 3h + to figure it wasn't related to live CD or hard drive health.

ANYWAY I ended up successfully reinstalling. Everything was fine under the sunshine until I decided I had to go to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo3gI.jpg) to change things. So I opted for the proprietary drivers of nVIDIA and not using the integrated chip.

So of curse it didn't work. Why would it. So now I have a black screen on startup and I'm starting to be desperate about ever using Ubuntu.

Can you please help me get Ubuntu to load to Unity? All I did was change the drivers to be used and restarted. Now I know there are wild answers going around but I really don't want to mess it up further by guessing the solution as I did earlier.

Comment: I think [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/225694) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)